# Python flask send file argument from one form to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests

This may get down voted for something so simple or so wrong, but I seem to be battling for whatever reason. I'm in flask. I have two forms. Each form is in a different route.

The goal is for form 1 to take an uploaded file (csv file), and upon submission redirect users to another form 2 where they map the column fields of the file. The part where I am struggling is using the `return redirect(url_for("form-2-url", file=uploaded_file))`  and then requesting that argument in form 2 such as `file = request.files.get('file')`. Keeps throwing  `Response 400` when submitting file in form 1. Full code:

```
@app.route('/import-data', methods=['GET', 'POST']) #Form 1 route    
def csv_import():    
    
    if request.method == "POST":
            
        #get the uploaded file    
        csv_file = request.files['csvfile']
        
        #redirect the user to form 2 url with the uploaded file
        return redirect(url_for('/import-data/map-fields', file=csv_file))
    
    return render_template('data-import-data.html')
    
@app.route('/import-data/map-fields', methods=['GET', 'POST']) #Form 2 route    
def map_fields():
    
    file = request.files.get('file') #request the file here from the redirect url arg
    
    df = pd.read_csv(file) #get the file into a pandas df to do some manipulation
    
    fieldmap = list(df.columns) #columns to map the fields
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        ...continue to work with the df and mapped fields
    return render_template('data-import-map-fields.html', fieldmap=fieldmap)
```

HTML seems fine. Nothing special, but I can share if it may be suspect. My pandas is a little rusty, not sure if there's simple mistake anywhere there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the `map_fields` function, what do you get if you `print(file)` after the `file=request.files.get('file')`? If that's successful, what is the output from `print(type(file))`?

Comment: @Ben It doesn't make it to `map_fields`. Upon post in `csv_import` an error gets thrown. However, I played around a little and moved `pandas` to read the file in `csv_import` and when printing it says it cannot find the relevant uploaded file. I am starting to think it may be the wrong question being asked, and more a case of saving the file to disk to carry data across to `map_fields`.